# Unable to display web part error on Custom List Form (New Item)

Tags: custom-controls, wss-3.0

I'm gonna take my chance at asking a question here because I really cannot find the root cause of this problem.

I'm working on a WSS 3.0 site, using SPD 2007 and I'm fairly new to Sharepoint development in general.

I'm customizing the DispForm.aspx page. The page is a simple edit page but at the end, I add a custom list form web part for adding comments (which are stored in another list) and below, a dataview for viewing the comments associated to the item displayed by the DispForm.aspx page.

What i want to do resembles the functionality displayed on this page, I inspired myself from it and you can in fact see my comments as the latest one :
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=209

Everything was working, until I delete all the comments i had made as a test. Now all i get from my Custom List Form is this "unable to display this web part error".

I've had a look at the logs, I understand what it is complaining about but i have no clue on how to fix it or even understand why there is such an error to begin with.

```
SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect() - selectArguments: IsEmpty=True, MaximumRows=0, RetrieveTotalRowCount=False, SortExpression=, StartRowIndex=0, TotalRowCount=-1
Error while executing web part: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to open the specified list item. ---> 
System.ArgumentException: **Value does not fall within the expected range**.     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.**GetItemById**(Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(Int32 id)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)     
at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator(IDataSource datasource, Boolean originalData)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform()
InnerException 1: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(Int32 id)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)
```

we're talking about a "new item" form, so i don't understand why I'm getting an error on GetItemById. What is it trying to get and how do i fix it?

Finally, I haven't changed the CAML query created by SPD. I did make change to the Comments list such as renaming or deleting unused columns but i don't think it is the cause of the problem because deleting the custom list form and recreating it didn't fix the issue.

Any clues as to where or what I should be looking at? I'm fresh out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Sharepoint Designer, Open the DispForm that you inserted the "Comments" custom list form into.
2. In Code view, find the DataFormWebPart for the list.
3. Locate the line `<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem"` and change the **DataSourceMode** to `DataSourceMode="List"`
4. Inside of the **ParameterBindings**, find `<ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId".....` and change it to `<ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="None" DefaultValue="0"/>`